# (Beginner) Rename file using Python - Refactor for a better answer

Tags: python, file, rename

(First post... very new to programming)

I needed to rename a bunch of files from 'This is a filename-123456.ext' to '123456-This is a filename.ext'

I managed to solve the problem using Python with the code below. I had to make 2 scripts because sometimes there are 5 numbers, but for the most part 6.

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir('.'): #not sure how to rename recursive sub-directories
    if filename != 'ren6.py': #included to not rename the script file
        start = filename[:-11]
        number = filename[-10:-4]
        ext = filename[-4:]
        newname = str(number) + '-' + str(start)+str(ext) #Unnecessary variable creation?
        os.rename(filename,newname)
```

I'm still learning and very curious of more efficient and elegant examples of to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Do the filenames have a consistent pattern with the hyphen in the middle (`a-b` to `b-a`)?

Comment: Can you provide an example filename?

Comment: I provided an example in the original question - "This is the filename pattern that all of the files are in-123456.txt" ... I wanted to change it to "123456-This is the filename pattern that all of the files are in.txt" ... All of the files are in that way title-123456.txt

Answer (score 4):

It may be safer and more powerful to use regular expressions.  This will only rename files that match the given pattern, which is [ANY SEQUENCE OF CHARACTERS][A DASH][NUMBERS][EXTENSION]

An added benefit to using this method is that you can run it multiple times on the same directory and it won't affect already renamed files.

You might also want to do a check to make sure the file you're renaming it to doesn't already exist (so that you don't overwrite an existing file).

```
import re


for filename in os.listdir('.')
    m = re.match(r'^(?P<name>.+)-(?P<num>\d+)(?P<ext>\.\w+)$', filename)
    if m:
        newname = '{num}-{name}{ext}'.format(**m.groupdict())
        if not os.path.exists(newname):
            os.rename(filename, newname)
```

I'll break down the regular expression

```
^(?P<name>.+)
```

The `^` indicates we will start matching at the beginning of the filename (as opposed to matching a middle part of the filename).  The `()` make this a regex group, so that we can access just that one part of the string match.  The `?P<name>` is just a way to apply a label to a particular group, so that we can refer it to by name later on.  In this case, we've given this group a label of `name`.

`.` will match any character, and `+` tells it to match 1 or more characters.

`-`

This will only match the `-` character

```
(?P<num>\d+)
```

Again, we've made this a group and given it a label of `num`.  `\d` will only match numbers and the `+` means it will match 1 or more numbers.

```
(?P<ext>\.\w+)$
```

Another group, another label.  The `\.` will only match a `.` and the `\w` will match word characters (i.e. letters, numbers, underscores).  Again, the `+` means it will match 1 or more characters.  The `$` ensures it matches all the way to the end of the string.

Comment: Hmm... I like the idea of making sure I'm not creating identical filenames, but it will take me some time to understand how this works. In this particular case every 6 or 5 digit number was unique, but for sure a best practice to employ. Thank you.

Comment: I will add regular expressions to my learning track. I think this would likely be very powerful and handy to know in many areas. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir('.')
    name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if '-' not in name:
        continue
    part1, part2 = filename.split('-')
    os.rename(filename, "{1}-{0}{2}".format(part2, part1, extension))
```

Comment: At my current level... I can just follow this logic. Very cool. I didn't think about splitting the filename into variables.

Comment: One important downside I notice is that this method is not [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) -- running this on a directory with filenames that have already been renamed will rename them back to the old, undesired name.

Comment: The code I used didn't take that into consideration either... and I did realize that each subsequent run would iterate the filename. I've been careful not to run it except the one time because there is no undo. Hmm... an undo would be nice.